# Generate JSON object with NewtonSoft in a single line

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the JSON library [NewtonSoft](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) to generate a JSON string:

```
JObject out = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                typ = "photos"
            });

            return out.ToString();
```

Output:

```
{
  "typ": "photos"
}
```

My question:
Is it possible to get the output in a single line like:

```
{"typ": "photos"}
```

Comment: why not just use C# to replace the new lines?

Comment: @sircapsalot That doesn't work so great when your data has spaces in it.

Answer (score 89):

You can use the overload of [`JObject.ToString()`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToString_1.htm) which takes [`Formatting`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm) as parameter:

```
JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    typ = "photos"
});

return obj.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 82):

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { typ = "photos" }, Formatting.None);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution (and answer)

Comment: I agree, this is the cleanest answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a one-liner to minify JSON that you only have a string for:

```
var myJson = "{\"type\"    :\"photos\"               }";
JObject.Parse(myJson).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)
```

Output:

```
{"type":"photos"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but what I do is this::

```
string postData = "{\"typ\":\"photos\"}";
```

EDIT:
After searching I found [this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) on Json.Net:

```
string json = @"{
  CPU: 'Intel',
  Drives: [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

and maybe you could use the info on [this](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) website.

But I'm not sure, if the output will be on one line... Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542810/using-jobject-and-jproperty-with-json-net-4-0) as a start, the JObject is new for me

Answer (score 0):

If someone here who doesn't want to use any external library in MVC, they can use the inbuilt `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`

One liner for that will be:

```
var JsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { typ = "photos" });
```

Comment: These days you'd probably use `System.Text.Json`