# Server side JSON minification .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to minify all json responses to single line instead of formatting. I heard Newtonsoft Json has some specific settings for this, but I am not sure where to put and what to put? Do I have to put it in Startup.cs and what is the setting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate JSON object with NewtonSoft in a single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917247/generate-json-object-with-newtonsoft-in-a-single-line)

Comment: @PaulKertscher: Kind of unrelated in this case due to the way its integrated in ASP.NET Core. See Mats391's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add it in the startup.cs like this

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o=>o.SerializerSettings.Formatting=Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

You can also configure any other settings you want.

Answer (score 1):

With the newtonsoft class you can do what you need.
In your writing object add the following code

```
Writer.Formatting = Formatting.None
```