# Compress/Minify a JSONObject before sending it over Http to Angular

Tags: .net, json, angular, minify

Is there a way to minify the json resulted from the get request ? I am using .Net Core for backend and Angular2 as a client and the data is loading painfully slow in my application because of the size of the Json. I would really appreciate any suggestion. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the JSON library NewtonSoft? If so you should be able to use formatting:

```
    JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(new
    {
        typ = "photos"
    });

    return obj.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Source: [Generate JSON object with NewtonSoft in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917247/generate-json-object-with-newtonsoft-in-a-single-line)

Comment: The Json is already formatted so that it appears without spaces, I thought there is a method to decrese it's size..:)

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output of JSON that you are expecting?