# I get \r\n and \ in my response Xamarin, how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, xamarin, newline

I send RQ using xamarin and parse JSON response, but in my response I get `\r\n` and `\` before every `"`.

I know some editors (like NuSphere(PhPed)) have option to disable adding those symbols, but I can't find any way to remove it in Xamarin.

```
    public async Task Post_RequestAsync()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(GET_RQ_ENDPOINT);
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await 
      client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: 
false);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BAD!");
        }

        await Task.Delay(1);

    }
```

This is a method I use to get response. I did some trimming and removing `\r\n` but is there any elegant solution to remove them?

Comment: Why not deal with it in the server end?

Comment: Can't do, not my API :-(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917247/generate-json-object-with-newtonsoft-in-a-single-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you deal with these problems in the server end, which usually occurs when there are spaces before or after the data string. If you deal with it in the server end , it will be simple and once and for all.When you get the response,you don't have to do any extra processing.

Of course, if you can't deal with it from the server end, you can only remove all needed characters by replacing regex like this:

```
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = Regex.Replace(content, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

Besides:  VS don't have this feature to get rid of those characters.This question is relative to our code in server end and client end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex for it

```
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = Regex.Replace(content, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

this should remove all needed characters.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but is there option in VS2019 to remove adding those characters?
I know that it can be done in NuSphere.

Comment: based on your code you are asking API for the data. How would you like VS to get rid of those characters? VS is IDE and we are talking about code