# Generating a list of json objects that Elasticsearch Bulk API will accept

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I'm looking into the Elasticsearch Bulk API so I'm experimenting on how i can generate the desired structure (see below) in a C# app:

```
{"update": { "_index": "products", "_id": "1" }}
{ "doc": { "name": "sample-product-name"}}
```

The above structure is what Elasticsearch expects you to conform too from my current understanding.

I've tried to use `JObject` to try and generate the structure but it's resulting in the following structure which is resulting in multiline, this is not what i want because the Elasticsearch API has strict rules

```
{
  "update": {
   "_index": "products",
   "_id": "1"
 }
 }{
    "doc": {
     "name": "sample-product-name"
  }
 }
```

Here is my current code. (NOTE: This may not be the best way to generate it but I am open to ideas):

```
    public string GenerateBulkApiRequestPayload()
    {
        dynamic root = new JObject();
        dynamic update = new JObject();
        update._index = "products";
        update._id = "1";

        root.update = update;

        dynamic docRoot = new JObject();
        dynamic doc = new JObject();
        doc.name = "myname";
        docRoot.doc = doc;

        var result = string.Concat(root.ToString() + docRoot.ToString());
        return result;
    }
```

Sending the payload in current structure results in the following error:

`Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object`

So how can I generate the desired structure. Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I found I can use the `ToString(Formatting.None)` and `Environment.NewLine`

All i had to do was pass in `Formatting.None` to the `ToString()` method on the two `JObjects` like so:

```
var result = string.Concat(root.ToString(Formatting.None) + Environment.NewLine + docRoot.ToString(Formatting.None));
```

This will result in the following which is what I wanted:

```
{"update": { "_index": "products", "_id": "1" }}
{ "doc": { "name": "sample-product-name"}}
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917247/generate-json-object-with-newtonsoft-in-a-single-line/13917445) helped me out.