# ASP.NET MVC ViewData doesn't work in frontend

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I hope you can help me with this error. I am using a ViewData to transfer data from controller to view.
In the script it shows me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//IMemoryCache cache

private const string _currencyCodes = "CURRENCY_CODES";

public ActionResult Index()
{
      if (_cache.Get(_currencyCodes) == null)
      {
          // GetData execute a stored procedure
           var datosCurrency = ad.GetData().Tables[0].Select().Select((x)  => new
          {
                Id = x.Field<int?>("Id"),
                Name = x.Field<string>("Name"),
                Code = x.Field<int?>("Code")
          }).ToArray();
          string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datosCurrency, Formatting.Indented);
         /*
         result shows this data
         "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 1,\r\n    \"Name\": \"Emma\",\r\n    \"Code\": 6\r\n   },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 2,\r\n    \"Name\": \"Roberth\",\r\n    \"Code\": 8\r\n   }\r\n]"
         */
         _cache.Set(_currencyCodes, result, cacheEntryOptions);
      }

      ViewData[_currencyCodes] = _cache.Get(_currencyCodes);
      return View();
   }
```

here

```
<script>
      var result = Html.Raw(@ViewData["CURRENCY_CODES"].ToString())';
       var CURRENCY_CODES = JSON.parse(result);
</script>
```

As you can see, in the script it shows the data but I have the error.

```
var result = '[Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
{
      "Id": 1,
       "Name": "Emma",
       "Code": 6
},
{
        "Id": 2,
       "Name": "Roberth",
      "Code": 8
}
]';
```

I don't understand this error.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't have a multi line string in javascript which is what you have. Use `Foramat.None` when serialising [Releated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13917298/4665). Or use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
result shows this data
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 1,\r\n    \"Name\": \"Emma\",\r\n    \"Code\": 6,\r\n   },\r\n  {\r\n    \"Id\": 2,\r\n    \"Name\": \"Roberth\",\r\n    \"Code\": 8,\r\n   }\r\n]"
*/
```

recheck your result at `\"Code\": 8,`. You can test your JSON result at JSON valitaor online

Update:
Let's try to console log. You may found the solution;

```
<script>
      var viewData = @ViewData["CURRENCY_CODES"];
      console.log(viewData);
      var result = Html.Raw(viewData)';
      console.log(result);
      var CURRENCY_CODES = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(CURRENCY_CODES);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the comma, But the json is ok.